# Search data and merge one to the other in this the same string data

Tags: c#, string

There is some string:

101,13,12,37511722,97,13,12,17515162,-9,17,-9,15,14,13,12,27515813,["ID","31477164","2000.00","100.00000000","36477059","2020-11-02T18:52:50","23477065"]

I have to look up numbers without "" and combine them with the numbers in "".
My numbers are without '.', and they have more than 3 characters.
It should look like this:

```
37511722,"31477164"
17515162,"36477059"
27515813,"23477065"
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your requirements aren't clear at all. For instance, `101` isn't in quotes either. Why didn't you use that? Or `13` or `12`. None of the numbers in the top row are in quotes.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a code-writing service. What specific part of this programming problem are you having difficulty with? Parsing the input? Filtering the results? Show the code you've written, and explain how its behavior isn't what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't have any, but I figured someone would give me an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is *unclear*, you have too many number; however, if you actually want to

> ...have to look up **positive integer** numbers (**at least 4 digits** long) without `""` and combine them with the numbers in `""`...

where **(bold)** condition is mine, you can try matching with a help of *regular expressions* left and right numbers; for given data:

```
 string data = "101,13,12,37511722,97,13,12,17515162,-9,17,-9,15,14,13,12,27515813,[\"ID_DYSPOZYCJI\",\"31477164\",\"2000.00\",\"100.00000000\",\"36477059\",\"2020 - 11 - 02T18: 52:50\",*\"23477065\"*] ";
```

you can put `left` and `right` matches as follow:

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  var left = Regex
    .Matches(data, @"[0-9]{4,}")
    .Cast<Match>();
   
  var right = Regex
    .Matches(data, @"\""[0-9]{4,}\""")
    .Cast<Match>();
```

You can combine `left` and `right` if you want:

```
  var result = left
    .Zip(right, (l, r) => $"{l},{r}")
    .ToArray(); // <- let's have an array

  // You can further combine array into a single string 
  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result);
```

Let's have a look:

```
  Console.Write(report);
```

Outcome:

```
37511722,"31477164"
17515162,"36477059"
27515813,"23477065"
```

Comment: My numbers are more than 3 characters and they are only digits or digits with "".

Comment: @Wojciech: if numbers to match are guaranteed to have `4` digits (which excludes `101`), we can change `8` into `4` in the pattern. See my edit

Comment: This is new knowledge for me! Thank you very much!